# How to show a control over and above among all controls wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, controls, z-index

I have a main window which consist some user controls.like below

```
<Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                        <controls:FileControl x:Name="FileControl" />
                        <controls:FControl x:Name="FControl"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <controls:MessagesControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MessagesControl" />
                </Grid>
```

Now inside FControl i have a stack panel which consist many controls like below and a list box which is visible while typing something in textbox, can say like autocomplete.

```
<Expander>
<StackPanel>
<textBox></textBox>
<ComboBox></ComboBox>
  <ListBox Panel.ZIndex="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"  Visibility="{Binding VisibiltyAttr}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, 
                                        Path=DataContext.SelectionCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
```

Now problem is that this Listbox is taking up space when it is visible on window. I want to show this ListBox to display over and above all controls including other usercontrols which are on main window.
How to show this ListBox overlap other controls.Please suggest the solutions, i tried z-index on listbox but did not work.

Comment: Do you want it to popup when needed?  Make it a separate window.

Comment: Is there no solution to do this in same usercontrol? i have done all coding in same viewmodel.

Comment: You could put the listbox in a popup or adorner. Or just on top of everything else by moving it into the window's outer grid. Switch it's visibility between collapsed and visible.